# Jpg with black background (or completely white) when extracted via PDFBox from a PDF file

Tags: java, image, pdf, jpeg, pdfbox

I need to extract images from a PDF and I am doing it via PDFBox (v 1.8.9).
It works well the 90% of cases but I have some images that when extracted are saved with black background (or are completely white) even if they look perfectly good in the original pdf. I imagine it is something with those jpgs files. What should I check in the jpgs? 
I am trying to see If I can upload an example pdf

This is the relevant (quite standard) piece of code...

```
    String pdfFile = promptForPDFFile(jf, "Select PDF file");
    // Load pdf file
    PDDocument document=PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
    //Get the pdf pages
    List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
    int pagetot = pages.size();

    int pagenum = 1;
    while( iter.hasNext() )
    {
        // Cycle on the pages for the images
        PDPage page = (PDPage)iter.next();

        PDResources resources = page.getResources();
        PDFTextStripper textStripper=new PDFTextStripper(); 
        textStripper.setStartPage(pagenum);
        textStripper.setEndPage(pagenum);
        Map images = resources.getImages();

        // Get page text content and use it as file name
        String pagecontent= textStripper.getText(document); 
        pagecontent = pagecontent.replaceAll("\n", "");
        pagecontent = pagecontent.replaceAll("\r", "");
        if( images != null )
        {
            Iterator imageIter = images.keySet().iterator();
            while( imageIter.hasNext() )
            {
                String key = (String)imageIter.next();
                PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage)images.get( key );
                File tempdir = new File(tempPath+"/temp/");
                tempdir.mkdirs();

                String name = tempPath+"/temp/"+pagecontent;
                //System.out.println( "Writing image:" + name );


                //Write the image to file
                image.write2file( name );


            }
        }
        pagenum ++;
        if (pagenum % 10 ==0)
        {
            System.out.print("\n--- "+ pagenum +"/"+pagetot);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please upload a PDF somewhere, and tell which of the images are not correct. Make sure that jai_imageio.jar and levigo plugins are in your classpath. Even then, there might still be problems with CMYK colorspace images. That has been solved in the unreleased 2.0 version.

Comment: They are images from a customer. I would prefer to send you the pdf via mail, if possible (and if this is not contrary to SO policy)...Could you provide me an email and I will send you a working pdf and a non working one. In the mean time I check your suggestion about the plugins.

Comment: sure, send it to tilman at snafu dot de. If possible, send a small file, i.e. the whole mail shouldn't be larger than 5MB. Only the non working PDF is needed. Mention details, i.e. what images you don't get correctly.

Comment: I have sent you the pdf. FYI, it seems not a problem related with the two plugins you indicated in your first comment. I have added them in my classpath, without any visible improvement.

Comment: I'm writing the answer. You'll probably like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran [ExtractImages.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/1.8/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.java?view=markup&sortby=date) against the two files you sent me. The problem file has CMYK images, as can be seen with this screenshot from PDFDebugger: 
[image]

The problem is that the 1.8 version doesn't handle CMYK images properly.

But there's a trick: 
The images are encoded with the DCTDecode filter, which is JPEG. You have "real JPEGs" in the PDF.

I am able to extract your images properly by using the "-directJPEG" option of that tool, which bypasses the decoding mechanism of PDFBox, and just saves the JPEG files "as is".

Note that while this works nicely with your files, it doesn't work properly if the images have an external colorspace specified in the PDF.

Here's the full source code. See writeJpeg2file() for the raw extraction details.

```
public class ExtractImages
{
    private int imageCounter = 1;

    private static final String PASSWORD = "-password";
    private static final String PREFIX = "-prefix";
    private static final String ADDKEY = "-addkey";
    private static final String NONSEQ = "-nonSeq";
    private static final String DIRECTJPEG = "-directJPEG";

    private static final List<String> DCT_FILTERS = new ArrayList<String>();

    static
    {
        DCT_FILTERS.add( COSName.DCT_DECODE.getName() );
        DCT_FILTERS.add( COSName.DCT_DECODE_ABBREVIATION.getName() );
    }

    private ExtractImages()
    {
    }

    /**
     * This is the entry point for the application.
     *
     * @param args The command-line arguments.
     *
     * @throws Exception If there is an error decrypting the document.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        ExtractImages extractor = new ExtractImages();
        extractor.extractImages( args );
    }

    private void extractImages( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        if( args.length < 1 || args.length > 4 )
        {
            usage();
        }
        else
        {
            String pdfFile = null;
            String password = "";
            String prefix = null;
            boolean addKey = false;
            boolean useNonSeqParser = false;
            boolean directJPEG = false;
            for( int i=0; i<args.length; i++ )
            {
                if( args[i].equals( PASSWORD ) )
                {
                    i++;
                    if( i >= args.length )
                    {
                        usage();
                    }
                    password = args[i];
                }
                else if( args[i].equals( PREFIX ) )
                {
                    i++;
                    if( i >= args.length )
                    {
                        usage();
                    }
                    prefix = args[i];
                }
                else if( args[i].equals( ADDKEY ) )
                {
                    addKey = true;
                }
                else if( args[i].equals( NONSEQ ) )
                {
                    useNonSeqParser = true;
                }
                else if( args[i].equals( DIRECTJPEG ) )
                {
                    directJPEG = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if( pdfFile == null )
                    {
                        pdfFile = args[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(pdfFile == null)
            {
                usage();
            }
            else
            {
                if( prefix == null && pdfFile.length() >4 )
                {
                    prefix = pdfFile.substring( 0, pdfFile.length() -4 );
                }

                PDDocument document = null;

                try
                {
                    if (useNonSeqParser)
                    {
                        document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(pdfFile), null, password);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document = PDDocument.load( pdfFile );

                        if( document.isEncrypted() )
                        {
                            StandardDecryptionMaterial spm = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(password);
                            document.openProtection(spm);
                        }
                    }
                    AccessPermission ap = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();
                    if( ! ap.canExtractContent() )
                    {
                        throw new IOException(
                            "Error: You do not have permission to extract images." );
                    }

                    List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
                    Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
                    while( iter.hasNext() )
                    {
                        PDPage page = (PDPage)iter.next();
                        PDResources resources = page.getResources();
                        // extract all XObjectImages which are part of the page resources
                        processResources(resources, prefix, addKey, directJPEG);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if( document != null )
                    {
                        document.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeJpeg2file(PDJpeg image, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try
        {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename + ".jpg");
            InputStream data = image.getPDStream().getPartiallyFilteredStream(DCT_FILTERS);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int amountRead;
            while ((amountRead = data.read(buf)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buf, 0, amountRead);
            }
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(data);
            out.flush();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (out != null)
            {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void processResources(PDResources resources, String prefix, 
            boolean addKey, boolean directJPEG) throws IOException
    {
        if (resources == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Map<String, PDXObject> xobjects = resources.getXObjects();
        if( xobjects != null )
        {
            Iterator<String> xobjectIter = xobjects.keySet().iterator();
            while( xobjectIter.hasNext() )
            {
                String key = xobjectIter.next();
                PDXObject xobject = xobjects.get( key );
                // write the images
                if (xobject instanceof PDXObjectImage)
                {
                    PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage)xobject;
                    String name = null;
                    if (addKey) 
                    {
                        name = getUniqueFileName( prefix + "_" + key, image.getSuffix() );
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        name = getUniqueFileName( prefix, image.getSuffix() );
                    }
                    System.out.println( "Writing image:" + name );
                    if (directJPEG && "jpg".equals(image.getSuffix()))
                    {
                        writeJpeg2file((PDJpeg) image, name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        image.write2file(name);
                    }
                    image.clear(); // PDFBOX-2101 get rid of cache ASAP
                }
                // maybe there are more images embedded in a form object
                else if (xobject instanceof PDXObjectForm)
                {
                    PDXObjectForm xObjectForm = (PDXObjectForm)xobject;
                    PDResources formResources = xObjectForm.getResources();
                    processResources(formResources, prefix, addKey, directJPEG);
                }
            }
        }
        resources.clear();
    }

    private String getUniqueFileName( String prefix, String suffix )
    {
        String uniqueName = null;
        File f = null;
        while( f == null || f.exists() )
        {
            uniqueName = prefix + "-" + imageCounter;
            f = new File( uniqueName + "." + suffix );
            imageCounter++;
        }
        return uniqueName;
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage requirements and exit.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "Usage: java org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractImages [OPTIONS] <PDF file>\n" +
            "  -password  <password>        Password to decrypt document\n" +
            "  -prefix  <image-prefix>      Image prefix(default to pdf name)\n" +
            "  -addkey                      add the internal image key to the file name\n" +
            "  -nonSeq                      Enables the new non-sequential parser\n" +
            "  -directJPEG                  Forces the direct extraction of JPEG images regardless of colorspace\n" +
            "  <PDF file>                   The PDF document to use\n"
            );
        System.exit( 1 );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks... it works perfectly :) Now I have to discriminate between extracted CMYK images and "non" CMYK ones because my work is not finished (I need to resize them...). But this is another story :)

Comment: java ImageIO is not very good and can't read CMYK jpeg files... maybe twelvemonkeys can help. https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys

Comment: Thanks, I will try that also because when resizing the images I get a nice salmon background color which obviously is not what the customer wants... do you think it is related with it?

Comment: @vindalooman I didn't test resizing your images so I can't comment for sure, I viewed them with IrfanView. However the "salmon background" is familiar to me in connection with CMYK images :-(  The good thing with  twelvemonkeys is that it is actively supported, unlike java ImageIO.

Comment: Resizing with irfanview works fine indeed... this afternoon I will have a look to twelvemonkeys.

Comment: Twelvemonkeys did the trick... now I just have to polish a bit the code but I have a working version. Thanks a lot for the support.